# Calculate tax per sessionID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table "Customer_Trans" and contains the following columns:

| Date | CustomerID | SessionID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/9/2020 | 485789 | 23 | 0,4 |
| 9/9/2020 | 485789 | 24 | 620 |
| 9/9/2020 | 485789 | 25 | 60 |

I want to calculate taxes per amount as follow:
For the first 100$ I have 0% tax, from 100,01$ - 500$ the tax needs to be 15% and from 500,01$ and above the tax needs to be 20%.

For instance, on the second row I have 620$, I have to substract the first 100$(0% tax) and I will have 520$.

For the amount of 500$ the tax need to be 15% (500 * 0,15) and the rest of the amount, 20$, tax need to be 20% (20 * 0,2).

I would like to avoid CTE (common table expression), but if not I will do it this way.

Comment: Kindly provide the desired sample output as well.

Comment: and please clarify why 20 $ in the example are under 20% tax

Comment: just use `case` expression to evaluate and calculate the tax for each of the tier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Customer_Trans
CREATE TABLE #Customer_Trans
(
[Date] date NULL,
CustomerID int NULL,
SessionID INT NULL,
Amount DECIMAL(18,4) NULL,
Tier1 DECIMAL(18,4) NULL,
Tier2 DECIMAL(18,4) NULL

)

INSERT INTO #Customer_Trans (Date,CustomerID,SessionID,Amount)
VALUES('9/9/2020',485789,23,0.4)
,('9/9/2020',485789,24,620)
,('9/9/2020',485789,25,60)
,('9/9/2020',485789,26,160.94)
,('9/9/2020',485789,27,502.24)

SELECT 
Date,CustomerID,SessionID,Amount,
CASE WHEN Amount > 500 THEN (.15*400)+(.2*(Amount-500)) ELSE 0 END AS Tier1,
CASE WHEN Amount > 100 AND Amount<500.0001 THEN (.15*(Amount-100)) ELSE 0 END AS Tier2
FROM #Customer_Trans
```

As a side note, in your description I believe you had a flaw inasmuch that the 620 transaction would be
400 * 15% + 120 * 20%
as the Tax Tiers you specified were 100 & 500 only, thus the 15% attracts values between 100.01 and 500.00 only, this for an amount of 620, the final 120 is subject to 20% tier.

Comment: thank you....to fix a little bit the case when statement...                                                     
    CASE WHEN Amount> 500 THEN (.15*500)+(.2*(Amount-500)) ELSE 0 END AS Tier1,    
    CASE WHEN Amount> 100 AND Amount<=500 THEN (.15*Amount) ELSE 0 END AS Tier2